# How to access QModelIndex row from QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have this in my QML code:

```
TreeView {
    ...
    onExpanded: {
        console.log("onExpanded called", index)
    }
}
```

And this is the output when it's called:

```
QModelIndex(1,0,0x5d9f5a0,TreeModel(0x5deae90))
```

how do I access the first value (`1`) inside QML code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you've got an Object in QML and you don't know how to access it's properties, you can always use: `Object.keys(obejectInQuestion)`.

At least for the `QModelIndex` you get for the `ListModel` the getter `row()` is used for the property `row`. So to access it, use: `myQModelIndexThingy.row` instead of `myQModelIndexThingy.row()`

Comment: mind blown. The source for the class QModelIndex doesn't have any Q_PROPERTIES, so where do these properties come from?

Comment: Is there any answer to the lack of `Q_PROPERTY`s question? I found [these](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmodelindex-and-related-classes-in-qml.html) docs for Qt6, but I am using Qt 5.12, and cannot find the relevant documentation of this feature.

Comment: It looks like it may have been just undocumented prior to Qt6 as the preface says the features have been available since Qt 5.5.